# Singularity include box-sizing and clearfix

Tags: mixins, compass-sass, singularitygs

I´d like to add some [Output Options](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Output-Options) to my [Singularitygs](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity) Setup.
1. border-box
2. clearfix

But i get some errors:

### _base.scss

```
@import 'singularitygs';
$include-border-box: true;
$include-clearfix: true;

$grids: 12;
$gutters: 1/3; 

*, *:before, *:after {
  @include box-sizing('border-box');
}

#foo {
  @include clearfix;
}

...
```

### config.rb

```
require 'singularitygs' ...
```

### Terminal log

```
sass/partials/_base.scss: Undefined mixin 'box-sizing'.)
```

Comment: Sharing your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock might help.

Comment: how did you solved it?